# Creating a drawing in Creo

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

How would I make a drawing similar to this ? Would I have to use Creo parametric draw a sketch and then convert this into a drawing ?

Or would I need to use a different Creo software ?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this program offer a "users manual" that provides instruction for creating/drawing a 2D plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you suggest is fine, I've done this at occasion but I would prefer not to*. However, bear in mind that this is a manufacturing detail, not a design detail.

In general Creo is meant for making design details and manufacturing details should be handled by a CAM module downstream. Why? Well the design usually has a longer time span than the manufacturing detail, and manufacturing floor might want to interleave it with different jobs at different times and optimize for different needs.

* There are other strategies that you can employ instead. Just design the object you are building. Then make:

1. A secondary assembly that lays out the components and make a drawing out of that.
2. If all the parts go to the same design you may do this layout as a explode state.
3. Let the CAM module lay them out (this is best as it gives manufacturing much more flexibility, also most likely it can be auto optimized)

the benefit of this is that the instructions are associative with the actual designs and not a self contained drawing